# Split xts object by events

Tags: r, split, xts

I have an xts object with a handful of event indicators. I need to split it by certain events, so that all entries from a given event up to the next event will be saved in the same `xts`, eventually creating a list of `xts` objects, with each containing the event as the last entry with no other events of the same type.

an example:

```
ts = as.Date(Sys.Date()-99:0)
e1 = numeric(100);e1[10*1:10]=1
e2 = numeric(100);e2[15*1:6]=1
y  = 1:100  # just a sample content
xs = as.xts(cbind(e1,e2,y),order.by=ts)

ee = e1*e2==1  # the event in which both e1 and e2 are 1, should happen at 30,60,90

# here should be splitting function that gets xs and ee as parameters
# and should return a list of 4 xts: the first with the entries 1 through 30, 
# the second with entries 31 to 60, the third with entries 61 to 90, and the last
# with entries 91 to 100
```

Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cumsum(ee)` to create your grouping variable, then just call `split`.  You have to make a small change to the output of `cumsum`, since you want the `TRUE` values to be the last observation in the group (rather than the first).

```
split(xs, c(0,head(cumsum(ee),-1)))
split(xs,rev(cumsum(rev(ee))))  # grouping factors reversed
```